# HTML - Web Standards and Accessibility Validation Checks giving unsolvable errors?

Tags: html, forms, validation, label, accessibility

I have finished my website design and am doing my final validation checks to make sure it all meets w3 web standards and accessibility checks. However it seems to be giving unsolvable errors on my final html page.

The accessibility checks produce this error:

```
3.3 Input Assistance: Help users avoid and correct mistakes.

Success Criteria 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions (A)

Check 187: input element has more than one associated label.
Repair: Remove or modify the label elements so there is only one associated label for each form control.
Error Line 73, Column 1:
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <div id="headercontent">
            <h1>Lifelong Adventure</h1>
        </div>
 ...()
```

The wc3 web standards validation produces:

```
Validation Output: 10 Errors

Error Line 71, Column 17: Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier.
                    <label for "subname"> Enter Name: </label> 

Error Line 71, Column 25: Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier.
                    <label for "subname"> Enter Name: </label> 

Warning Line 71, Column 26: Attribute "subname" is not serializable as XML 1.0.
                    <label for "subname"> Enter Name: </label> 

Error Line 71, Column 26: Bad value for attribute for on element label: An ID must not be the empty string.
                    <label for "subname"> Enter Name: </label> 

Error Line 71, Column 26: Attribute "subname" not allowed on element label at this point.
                    <label for "subname"> Enter Name: </label> 

Error Line 73, Column 17: Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier.
                    <label for "subemail"> Enter Email: </label>

Error Line 73, Column 26: Quote " in attribute name. Probable cause: Matching quote missing somewhere earlier.
                    <label for "subemail"> Enter Email: </label>

Warning Line 73, Column 27: Attribute "subemail" is not serializable as XML 1.0.
                    <label for "subemail"> Enter Email: </label>      

Error Line 73, Column 27: Bad value for attribute for on element label: An ID must not be the empty string.
                    <label for "subemail"> Enter Email: </label>      

Error Line 73, Column 27: Attribute "subemail" not allowed on element label at this point.
                    <label for "subemail"> Enter Email: </label>      

Error Line 71, Column 26: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.
                    <label for "subname"> Enter Name: </label>

Error Line 73, Column 27: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.
                    <label for "subemail"> Enter Email: </label>
```

The code in question is:

```
<section id="subscribeEmail">
            <!--This section allows the user the option to subscribe to my blogs if they don't have an RRS feed. It only asks for a name and email address before sending it to my email address 
            where I can then store their email and add them to my CC every time I sent out a new bog post.-->
                <h3>Never Miss a Post:</h3>
                <form class="subscribe" action="mailto:tm_mitchell@hotmail.co.uk" method="post">
                    <label for "subname"> Enter Name: </label>
                        <input id="subname" title="name" class="sub" type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" placeholder="Full Name" required>     
                    <label for "subemail"> Enter Email: </label>    
                        <input id="subemail" title="email" class="sub" type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter email to subscribe" required>    
                    <input class="subsubmit" type="reset" value="Reset" id="Reset">
                    <input class="subsubmit" type="submit" value="Send" id="Submit">
                </form>
            </section>
```

So my question is why am I getting the seemingly unsolvable errors? Are they anything to worry about? Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that they are unsolvable?

Comment: You should specify which checking tool you are using. It seems to be partly faulty, as I point in my answer to a partial duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525636/html-accessibility-error-label-text-is-empty

Answer (score 2):

`for` in `<label for "subname">` is an attribute:

```
<label for="subname">
```

This should solve the bulk of your errors and warnings, as all of your `<label>` elements were being parsed incorrectly and were assumed to be labels for that one input element.

Comment: Now the accessibility check says this:                               

Check 188: Label text is empty.
Repair: Add text to the label element.
Error Line 75, Column 6:
<input class="subsubmit" type="reset" value="Reset" id="Reset">

Comment: @user3087735: Those error messages are written in plain English. Can you post your *entire* webpage?

Comment: Yes, it says I need to add text to the label element. As you can see in my sample line 75 doesn't have a label element. (line 75 = <input class="subsubmit" type="reset" value="Reset" id="Reset">)

Comment: @user3087735: Look at the lines above it for the closest one.

Comment: @user3087735: `<label for "subname">` isn't valid. Just search for ```<label for ``` and replace it with `<label for=`.

Comment: I have already changed that, forgot to copy it from my updated version. I have edited it to the current version.

Comment: They both contain text: <label for= "subname"> Enter Name: </label> <input id="subname" title="name" class="sub" type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" placeholder="Full Name" required> <label for= "subemail"> Enter Email: </label> <input id="subemail" title="email" class="sub" type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter email to subscribe" required>

Comment: @user3087735: Edit all of your HTML into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Is this not incorrect

```
<label for "subname">
```

change to

```
<label for="subname">
```

Comment: Do you know why I am getting the error: Label text is empty. Repair: Add text to the label element. Error Line 75, Column 6: <input class="subsubmit" type="reset" value="Reset" id="Reset"> ??

Comment: @user3087735: This seems to be the issue of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20525636/1591669).