# HTML Accessibility Error - Label text is empty?

Tags: html, forms, text, label, accessibility

I keep on getting this error even though the line stated to be containing the error doesn't have a label element?

```
3.3 Input Assistance: Help users avoid and correct mistakes.

Success Criteria 3.3.2 Labels or Instructions (A)

Check 188: Label text is empty.
Repair: Add text to the label element.
Error Line 75, Column 6:
<input class="subsubmit" type="reset" value="Reset" id="Reset">
```

The code is:

```
<section id="subscribeEmail">
            <!--This section allows the user the option to subscribe to my blogs if they don't have an RRS feed. It only asks for a name and email address before sending it to my email address 
            where I can then store their email and add them to my CC every time I sent out a new bog post.-->
                <h3>Never Miss a Post:</h3>
                <form class="subscribe" action="mailto:tm_mitchell@hotmail.co.uk" method="post">
                    <label for="sub-name">Enter Name: </label>
                        <input id="sub-name" title="name" class="sub" type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" placeholder="Full Name" required>        
                    <label for="sub-email">Enter Email: </label>    
                        <input id="sub-email" title="email" class="sub" type="text" size="35" maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter email to subscribe" required>   
                    <input class="subsubmit" type="reset" value="Reset" id="Reset">
                    <input class="subsubmit" type="submit" value="Send" id="Submit">
                </form>
            </section>
```

What is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should specify which software is issuing the message and what the line numbers are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accessibility testing tool used is faulty. It says that you should have a label for the reset button, but clause H44: [Using label elements to associate text labels with form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html) of WCAG 2.0 explicitly says that a label is **not** used for a reset button.

On the other hand, a reset button is almost always bad for accessibility and for normal use. As Jakob Nielsen, the usability specialist, [writes](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/): “The Web would be a happier place if virtually all Reset buttons were removed. This button almost never helps users, but often hurts them.”

Comment: The error can also be silenced by designating a title for the element. For example: <input type="reset" value="Reset Form" title="Reset Form"/>